# infinite while loop in last lines of code

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, infinite-loop

Could anyone please assist me with the following:

I have a code that reads a username and password then allows users to access a program. I have the first option to register a new user correct. I'm having a problem with an infinite loop problem with my last two lines of code. Id like to run a string stating that if an unregistered username is entered it returns with a string saying that there is no such registered user. The string just keeps running in the loop and is there anything I could do to change this.

> username: admin
>
> password: adm1n

my code is as follows:

```
users = {}  
with open ('user.txt', 'rt')as username:
    for line in username:
        username, password = line.split(",")
        users[username.strip()] = password.strip()  # strip removes leading/trailing whitespaces

uinput = input("Please enter your username:\n")
while uinput not in users:
    print("Username incorrect.")
    uinput = input("Please enter a valid username:/n")

if uinput in users:
            print ("Username correct")

with open('user.txt', 'rt') as password:
    for line in password:
        username, password = line.split(",")
        users[password.strip()] = username.strip()  # strip removes leading/trailing whitespaces

uinput2 = input("Please enter your password:\n")
while uinput2 not in users:
    print("Your username is correct but your password is incorrect.")
    uinput2 = input("Please enter a valid password:\n")

if uinput2 in users:
    password2 = ("Password correct")
    print (password2)

if password2 == ("Password correct"):
       menu = (input("\nPlease select one of the following options:\nr - register user\na - add task\nva - view all tasks\nvm - view my tasks\ne - exit\n"))
    if menu == "r" or menu == "R":
                new_user = (input("Please enter a new user name:\n"))
                new_password = (input("Please enter a new password:\n"))
                with open ('user.txt', 'a')as username:
                        username.write("\n" + new_user + ", " + new_password)
    elif menu == "a" or menu == "A":
                task = input("Please enter the username of the person the task is asigned to.\n")
        while task not in username:
                print("User not registered. Please enter a valid username:\n")
```

Comment: Neither of the loop variables change inside loop. Why would not you expect the loop to run infinite?

Comment: why do you use `while` ? Use `if` to display it only once. And put all code in loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a loop at the end that says

```
while task not in username:
    print("User not registered. Please enter a valid username:\n")
```

This is unfinished and will loop endlessly since if `task` is not in `username`, printing something will not change that fact so it will just loop and print again. You probably wanted to add something like

```
task = input("Please enter a valid username of a person the task is assigned to.\n")
```

Comment: i wanted to run a loop until the correct username was entered?

Comment: Does any one have any suggestions how to add a loop until the correct username is input?

Comment: what i wrote above would work, unless I am misunderstanding your question.

Comment: Thank you CMXU! You're right! Converting it to an input works perfectly!

Comment: Sure, no problem. Glad to help!